# Replace a tag with another tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to find a tag within an XML document, and replace it entirely with a new tag. I've got what I think should work below:

```
para = monograph.find('para', text='Some text.')
newpara = '<para>Some <emph type="bold">new</emph> text.</para>'
newpara = BeautifulSoup(newpara, 'xml')
para.replaceWith(newpara)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 211, in replace_with
my_index = self.parent.index(self)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Any advice?

Comment: what does `monograph.find('para', text='Some text.')` return?

Comment: The value of para is <para>Some text.</para>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [**replaceWith()**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) to achieve this, here is one way how to do it:

```
In [8]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [9]: tree = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div><para>Some text.</para></body></html>', 'xml')

In [10]: newpara = '<para>Some <emph type="bold">new</emph> text.</para>'

In [11]: newpara = BeautifulSoup(newpara, 'xml')

# here I use newpara.para as a shortcut to get the <para> element
# as a new BeautifulSoup will include wrapping tags
In [12]: tree.find('para', text='Some text.').replaceWith(newpara.para)
Out[12]: <para>Some text.</para>

In [13]: print tree
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html><body><div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div><para>Some <emph type="bold">new</emph> text.</para></body></html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, combining the find and the replacewith like you did does the trick. I'd already realized i needed to specify newpara.para, but it still wasn't working. In any case, it works now!