# BeautifulSoup - replace <tr> attributes based on <td>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do something where if the parent `<tr>` has a child of `<td>some string</td>` that matches a pre-defined string, replace the parent `<tr>` tag class.

Here's how the html looks -

```
<tr>
    <td>patterns</td>
    <td>password</td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>some item</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want it so that if any child `<td>` matches password, replace the parent `<tr>` with `<tr class="table-danger">`

Thanks,

Comment: So if `patterns` matches `password` then replace `patterns`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't safely wrap the html to be displayed - it should now be visible in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace a tag with another tag in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703280/replace-a-tag-with-another-tag-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: If a match is found, do you want to place the _entire_ `tr`, to `tr class="table-danger">`? and that would be the entire HTML.  Or you also want to keep the rest of the HTML?

Comment: Can you show an example of the full output expected?

Comment: Ahhh exactly what I'm looking for. Brilliant!

Comment: So the output would then be <tr class="table-danger"><td>patterns</td><td>password</td><td><ul><li>some item</li></ul></td></tr> I think I now how to do this now. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example using `:-soup-contains()` selector. *(Note: for older versions of BeautifulSoup, use `:contains()` instead)*.

I have commented the code providing an explanation:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pattern = "LOOK_FOR_ME"

html = """
<html>
 <body>
  <tr>
   <td>
    LOOK_FOR_ME
   </td>
   <td>
    LOOK_FOR_ME
   </td>
   <td>
    <ul>
     <li>
      some item
     </li>
    </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

match = soup.select_one(
    #  Select a `tr` with a preceding `td` that contains our pattern, with the next `td` containing our pattern
    f"tr > td:-soup-contains({pattern}) + td:-soup-contains({pattern})"
)

if match:
    # Replaces the `tr` with it's contents
    match.find_parent("tr").unwrap()
    # find the first `td` and insert before it the desired element
    match.find_previous("td").insert_before('tr class="table-danger">')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <body>
  tr class="table-danger"&gt;
  <td>
   LOOK_FOR_ME
  </td>
  <td>
   LOOK_FOR_ME
  </td>
  <td>
   <ul>
    <li>
     some item
    </li>
   </ul>
  </td>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Documentation:**

- [CSS selectors (`.select_one()`)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)
- [`:-soup-contains()`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains)
- [Adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)
- [`unwrap()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap)